# Why is this simple scala code taking so much memory and finally crashing? (Play framework 2.0)

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, anorm

I'm trying a simple scala code in play framework 2.0 to fill my db (other options exists, such as importing a SQL file directly within the database, but that's not the point) :

```
def filldb = Action {
  import play.api.db.DB
  import anorm._

  var result: Boolean = false

  val tuples: List[(Long, String)] = DB
    .withConnection("playground") { implicit c =>

      for (i <- 1 until 1000000) {
        SQL("""
            INSERT INTO article (
                id,
                title
            ) VALUES (
                """ + i + """,
                'Article no """ + i + """');"""
        ).executeUpdate()

        if (i % 1000 == 0) println("i:" + i)
      }

      val sqlQuery = SQL("select id, title from article order by id;")

      sqlQuery().map(row =>
        row[Long]("id") -> row[String]("title")).toList
    }
  Ok("done")
}
```

This runs well for a while (200K iterations), slows down, eats up memory progressively (up to 1.8GB), and finally crashes from lack of memory.

Can someone explain me what causes this behaviour?
It's clear that it's possible to code it in different ways, but the point is to understand what is wrong, so that the error would not be done in another context...

To be complete, here are the details :

- OS : mac 10.6.8
- play : 2.0
- database : mysql 5.5.12
- table :

  ```
  CREATE TABLE article (
  id bigint(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  title varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
  );
  ```

Tried this as weel, with no more success :

```
def filldb = Action {
  import play.api.db.DB
  import anorm._

  var result: Boolean = false
  val connection = DB.getConnection("playground")

  for (i <- 1 until 1000000) {
        SQL("""
            INSERT INTO article (
                id,
                title
            ) VALUES (
                """ + i + """,
                'Article no """ + i + """');"""
        ).executeUpdate()(connection)

        if (i % 1000 == 0) println("i:" + i)
      }

  val tuples: List[(Long, String)] = {

      val sqlQuery = SQL("select id, title from article order by id;")

      sqlQuery()(connection).map(row =>
        row[Long]("id") -> row[String]("title")).toList
    }

  connection.close()

  Ok("done")
}
```

Not better : stuck at 283k iterations...

Comment: What is that `var result: Boolean = false`?

Comment: something not used anymore ;-) removed.

Comment: Can you replace the for comprehension with a while loop?

Comment: I tried. Same result : 283K iterations and error :
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2734) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
 at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacity(ArrayList.java:167) ...

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that you might still be using the default in memory database. Can you check and make sure your conf/application.conf is not using jdbc:h2:mem:play? If so, all of your entries would be filling up your memory.

Also, each statement that you make opens a statement object that doesn't get closed until the end of the withConnection block. Since you have a million of them sitting in memory, that can build up. See http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaDatabase

You could try populating the DB outside of your query operation. I would experiment with doing 1000 batches of 1000 and seeing if that identifies your problem.

Comment: Here is the configuration : `db.playground.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.playground.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/playground"
db.playground.user="root"
db.playground.password="XXXX"`

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem lies here:

```
val tuples: List[(Long, String)] = {

  val sqlQuery = SQL("select id, title from article order by id;")

  sqlQuery()(connection).map(row =>
    row[Long]("id") -> row[String]("title")).toList
}
```

You are populating a map with all the rows form the database so you are fillng a Scala/Java data stucture with 1M of rows.

Do you really need one million of rows all at once? Or do you need them in paginated way (i.e the first 20 the second 20, etc,etc).

It's not a play problem, you  will encounter the same problem even with java and a single plain jdbc test. Tell us the real usage of tuples and we can provide some suggestions.